# Improve the performance of Java Web Application

Tags: java, web-applications

I am working with 3 tier web application which has the following technology stack:

- Java EE
- Servlet 3.0
- JSP 2.4
- Spring 3.0
- MySQL Database
- Tomcat Web Server

We launch this application using Mozilla Firefox browser. My problem is, application is facing performance issues while having large data on database.

We have around 10 JSP whereas each JSP is related with particular table in database. The problem is occurred while loading the particular JSP which has large data in the table. Logging in to the application also struck with the performance issue, and this also takes too long time to show the home page.

I need this application working with best performance. We don't want to lose our valuable clients due to the performance issues. I don't know where is the bottleneck, and what to do to tune performance of my application.

Answer (score 6):

Some advices:

- Make sure you use a database connection pool instead of manually opening your connections.
- Make sure to have the connections in the most narrow scope possible. This means, **never** as a field in a class nor higher.
- Tune up your database: apply indexes in tables based on your queries, partition our tables, adjust the statistics on your tables, etc.
- Tune up your queries: write them to follow the indexes in your tables, use `EXPLAIN` to check if the query uses indexes criteria or linear search, do not use subqueries in your queries, etc.
- Use pagination to display your tables. Preferably, use pages of small size at the beginning like 10 or 15 (or another defined value in your application) rows per table in a single view. The max size will depend on what you display. It's not the same displaying thumbnails for videos than displaying just plain text. Also, it also helps to know the amount of columns and their content, it's not the same displaying 250 rows of two columns that are plain numbers rather than displaying reports containing several columns.

Apart of following these, use a profiler like Visual VM or Java Mission Control or Yourkit to spot the bottlenecks on your application.

Comment: Not really an answer but its good advice nonetheless so +1 for you :) Stating a max of 100 records per page is a bit specific though, I'm sure 250 also works nice and speedy if there are only 2 columns to display. The key is to apply pagination.

Comment: @Gimby sorry for the late update.